# C# performant rounding that works across 0

Tags: c#, performance, integer, rounding, truncation

```
float x = 5;
Int16 x2 = (Int16)(x * 0.005);
```

x2 is a truncated/rounded version of x. Representing chunks of 200 units, as shown in the above code.

However the above code produces a larger interval across 0. An interval of 400 instead of 200.

```
x     x2   intended
-500  -2   -3
-300  -1   -2
-100  0    -1
100   0    0
300   1    1
500   2    2

-210  -1   -2
-190  0    -1
-20   0    -1
-10   0    -1
10    0    0
20    0    0
190   0    0
210   1    1
```

What is a perfomant way of fixing this?

Comment: What does _"produces a larger interval across 0"_ mean?

Comment: What numbers do you want to see for x2?

Comment: I've now included this information.

Comment: If you want the always-rounded down "floor" rather than the rounded-towards-zero truncation then call the aptly-named `Floor` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
float x = 5;
int16 x2 = (Int16)Math.Floor(x * 0.005);
```

`Math.Floor` description:

> Returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified double-precision floating-point number.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure because it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, but I suspect what you want is `Math.Floor`.  At least that works for all of your data points.